# How to design state for a blogging application that also works offline with recoiljs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, recoiljs

I'm trying to create a simple blogging application, and am trying to wrap my head around how I would set up the state in Recoil.

Say we have a simple REST API `/posts` that returns a paginated list of posts, without the full post content of each post.
The `/post/:id` endpoint returns a single full post including the content for a given post ID

What would be the optimal way to design the state in this application? To complicate things further, I'd also like for the state to be persisted in `localStorage` so that the application would work offline and be able to sync with the API later when back online, and also for caching purposes so we're not having to refetch data that's already been fetched (we can ignore this requirement for now though).

How should the state be designed in such an application? Really struggling to wrap my head around what should be an atom, atomFamily, selector, selectorFamily, etc. Also I'd love to see a GitHub repo or code sample of another recoil application of similar complexity including syncing with an API, since the client-side todo list in the tutorial is extremely trivial.